# python insert image to .odt file

Tags: python, image

I have a question, can you insert an image to a libreoffice file using python?

I know how to insert text using this code:

```
file = open("test.odt", "w")
file.write("testing text")
file.close()
```

I would prefer not to use outside libraries because the target computer only has python and tkinter installed.

Is there a way to insert an image in python?

Comment: With that code you are not writing text in a libreoffice file, you are just creating a text file with a .odt extension. Your best option is to use a library. Of course it can be done without them, but it wouldn't be trivial and most likely it would be redundant.

Comment: ah, ok thanks, I got an idea, cheers.